# Git Bash で、ローカルからリモートリポジトリを作成できない

Tags: git, git-bash

ローカルからGit Bash 経由で、リモートリポジトリを作成することが出来ません。

**環境**
Windows
Git Bash

---

**作業内容**
ローカルからGit Bash 経由で、リモートリポジトリを作成しようとするが、エラー発生

本来であれば、下記時点で、リモートリポジトリが作成されるのですか？
GitHubを見ても作成されていませんでした。

```
user@Windowsユーザー名 /L/git/日本 (master)
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:GitHubユーザー名/test20200601_osaka.git
```

下記が表示されたので、リモートリポジトリが(どこかに)作成されたと思ったのですが

```
user@Windowsユーザー名 /L/git/日本 (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:GitHubユーザー名/test20200601_osaka.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:GitHubユーザー名/test20200601_osaka.git (push)
```

実際に試すとエラーになります

```
user@Windowsユーザー名 /L/git/日本 (master)
$ git push -u origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

**Q**
ローカルからGit Bash 経由で、リモートリポジトリを作成するにはどうすれば良いですか？
※GitHubからリモートリポジトリ作成することは出来ました(pushまで出来ました)
※Git Bash 経由で(出来ればプライベート)リモートリポジトリを作成したい

Comment: gitのリモートリポジトリの作成って本当に、ローカルのgitコマンドで可能なのですか？可能との情報があれば、そのリソースを提示いただけないでしょうか。個人的には機能境界の観点で難しいのではと思います。たとえば、WebAPIで作成するというのなら話は分かりそうです。

Comment: re9 さんは憶測に基づいて話を進める傾向がありますが、一次情報のマニュアル等を調べる癖を付けることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` コマンドから GitHub のリポジトリ作成は出来ません。ブラウザから GitHub にアクセスして手動でリポジトリを作成する必要があります。

あなたが実行した `git remote add` はリモートリポジトリの **URL** を登録するだけであって、乱暴に言えばブラウザでお気に入りにURLを登録するのと同じです。
URLを登録したからといって、その宛先に何かが勝手に作られるわけではありません。

どうしてもコマンドラインから GitHub のリポジトリを作成したい場合には、[hub](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html) コマンドや [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/) の利用を検討してみてください。